# DD4T.ContentModel.XmlSerializers

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.2

I am using DXA 1.2 and OOB DD4T Dlls. Everything seems to be working fine with OOB Views and other views that I wrote except for one page + region + Entity view combination.

DXA keeps throwing an error that XMLSerializers DLL v2.0.4.0 is needed. I am not sure why DD4T needs this DLL only for my content and works fine for all other Components and Schemas.

The Schema I am using has only one Text Box (no RTF) field and the view uses only DXARaw method to write out the content of the text box to the page. Is there any repository from where I can pick this version of the DLL and install it in GAC? I was able to find V2.0.7.0 but this is not helping due to the DLL's version difference.

Here is the complete Stack Trace -

> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'DD4T.ContentModel.XmlSerializers, Version=2.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4450e3c7f68bf872' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>      DD4T.Serialization.XmlSerializerService.Deserialize(String input) +0
>      DD4T.Factories.PageFactory.GetIPageObject(String pageStringContent) +280
>      DD4T.Factories.PageFactory.TryFindPage(String url, IPage& page) +1071
>      Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultProvider.GetPage(String url, Localization localization) +168
>      Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultProvider.GetPageModel(String url, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes) +190
>      Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageUrl) +461
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +130
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +242
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +12
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +139
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +112
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41() +452
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41() +452
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +37
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +241
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Comment: Have you tried to debug the application and see if the problem is as you mention the missing `DD4T.ContentModel.XmlSerializers` or could it be one of its dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all is well, your Pages contain DD4T JSON.
However, if a Page does not contain JSON (for example, you accidentally used the Default Page Template which renders ugly HTML), DD4T can't deserialize and will try to fallback to XML deserialization.

For DXA we don't support the legacy DD4T XML format, so we don't even ship the XMlSerializers assembly, resulting in the given error.

Bottom line: your Page problably uses the wrong Page Template. You can verify that using a CM Preview. That should render DD4T JSON, not HTML.

Comment: At times silly mistakes like this costs a lost of time :)